# Get selected value of Dynamics AutoComplete field

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have an context sensitive AutoComplete field on my form which gets data from a service and populates the autocomplete field with the result if data was found and shows the field with "showAutoComplete":

The User searches for a street starting with "Main" and the method will get all streets starting with "Main" and show the result of all "Main*" streets in the dropdown.

```
function _addOnKeyPressStreet(executionContext) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    var input = formContext.getControl("address1_line1").getValue();

    var result = null;
    resultSet = {
        results: new Array()
    };

    if (input != null && input.length > 3) {
        try {
            var streets = getLokalisation("POST", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", input);
            var suggestions = new Array();
            $(streets)
                .find('localisationen').find('localisation').find('text')
                    .each(function(){
                        suggestions.push(this.innerHTML.toString());
                    });
            result = streets.filter(n => n.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase()));;
        }
        catch (exp) {
            alert(exp);
        }
    }

    if (result != null && result.length > 0) {
        for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            resultSet.results.push({
                id: i,
                fields: [result[i]]
            });
        }
        executionContext.getEventSource().showAutoComplete(resultSet);
    } 
    else {
        executionContext.getEventSource().hideAutoComplete();
    }
}
```

If I click on an entry, lets say "Mainstreet" in the dropdown the text in the field is shown correctly as "Mainstreet".

But If I get the value by using

```
formContext.getControl("address1_line1").getValue();
```

I always get the old value which was "Main" (The value the user searched for).

Even if add the AddOnChange-Eventhandler on this autocomplete field and try to get the value in the OnChange-Event:

```
function _addOnChangeStreet(executionContext) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    alert(formContext.getControl("address1_line1").getValue()); // Always the "old" value
}
```

The value is still "Main" instead of "Mainstreet".

How do I get the selected value from this autocomplete field??

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

FOUND SOLUTION:

For those who struggle with the same issue, the solution is trivial!

Instead of getting the value by using:

```
formContext.getControl("address1_line1").getValue();
```

you need to use:

```
formContext.getAttribute("address1_line1").getValue();
```

This will get the value which was selected in the autocomplete dropdown.